# Cause: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I am getting this error -

> ERROR: Cause: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Whenever I am doing Gradle sync. 
It also says that there is an SSL exception and also `resource not found exception for org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.41`.

However, I don't understand why am I getting issues about kotlin when I am writing the code in Java and not kotlin.

I am using Android Studio 3.5

Things I have tried till now :

-Changing jcenter() from https to http

-Tried to run on company as well as home network but got the same issue

-Downloaded the certificate and added it

-Uninstalled and Installed android studio

Also please note that the issuer of the certificate that is in my server certificate shows my company proxy and not CA no matter if its getting installed at home or on company network. I read it somewhere that the certificate issuer should be CA.

Error Log: Kotlin Part

```
        Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.41.
        Required by:
            project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0
            project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.5.0
            project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:26.5.0
            project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:3.5.0
            project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0 > androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:3.5.0
            project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.5.0 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:26.5.0
            project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.5.0 > com.android.tools:common:26.5.0
            project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.5.0 > com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:26.5.0
            project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.5.0 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:26.5.0
            project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.5.0 > com.android.tools:sdklib:26.5.0 > com.android.tools:repository:26.5.0
            project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.5.0 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:26.5.0 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:26.5.0
        Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.41.
        Caused by: org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.3.41/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.41.pom'.
            at org.gradle.internal.resource.ResourceExceptions.failure(ResourceExceptions.java:74)
            at org.gradle.internal.resource.ResourceExceptions.getFailed(ResourceExceptions.java:57)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.downloadByCoords(DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.java:140)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.downloadStaticResource(DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.java:99)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.java:65)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.metadata.AbstractRepositoryMetadataSource.parseMetaDataFromArtifact(AbstractRepositoryMetadataSource.java:70)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.metadata.AbstractRepositoryMetadataSource.create(AbstractRepositoryMetadataSource.java:60)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.metadata.DefaultMavenPomMetadataSource.create(DefaultMavenPomMetadataSource.java:38)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.metadata.RedirectingGradleMetadataModuleMetadataSource.create(RedirectingGradleMetadataModuleMetadataSource.java:51)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver.resolveStaticDependency(ExternalResourceResolver.java:247)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.MavenResolver.doResolveComponentMetaData(MavenResolver.java:127)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver$RemoteRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(ExternalResourceResolver.java:451)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRepository$ResolveAndCacheRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(CachingModuleComponentRepository.java:375)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.lambda$resolveComponentMetaData$5(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:153)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.lambda$tryResolveAndMaybeBlacklist$18(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:222)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.tryResolveAndMaybeBlacklist(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:236)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.tryResolveAndMaybeBlacklist(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:221)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.performOperationWithRetries(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:214)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:152)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ComponentMetaDataResolveState.process(ComponentMetaDataResolveState.java:69)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ComponentMetaDataResolveState.resolve(ComponentMetaDataResolveState.java:61)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.findBestMatch(RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.java:139)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.findBestMatch(RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.java:120)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.resolveModule(RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.java:93)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.resolve(RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.java:64)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.ComponentResolversChain$ComponentMetaDataResolverChain.resolve(ComponentResolversChain.java:95)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.clientmodule.ClientModuleResolver.resolve(ClientModuleResolver.java:64)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.ComponentState.resolve(ComponentState.java:196)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.ComponentState.getMetadata(ComponentState.java:146)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.DownloadMetadataOperation.run(DownloadMetadataOperation.java:31)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.access$1500(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:49)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$ParentPreservingQueueWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:444)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable.runOperation(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:231)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable.access$600(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:173)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable$1.create(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:210)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable$1.create(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:204)
            at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:189)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable.runBatch(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:204)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable.run(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:178)
            at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
            at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
            at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.3.41/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.41.pom'.
            at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:91)
            at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRawHead(HttpClientHelper.java:68)
            at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performHead(HttpClientHelper.java:72)
            at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpResourceAccessor.getMetaData(HttpResourceAccessor.java:66)
            at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultExternalResourceConnector.getMetaData(DefaultExternalResourceConnector.java:63)
            at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.AccessorBackedExternalResource.getMetaData(AccessorBackedExternalResource.java:201)
            at org.gradle.internal.resource.BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator$1.call(BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator.java:61)
            at org.gradle.internal.resource.BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator$1.call(BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator.java:58)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
            at org.gradle.internal.resource.BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator.getMetaData(BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator.java:58)
            at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor$1.get(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:102)
            at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor$1.get(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:82)
            at org.gradle.cache.internal.ProducerGuard$AdaptiveProducerGuard.guardByKey(ProducerGuard.java:97)
            at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.getResource(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:82)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.downloadByCoords(DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.java:135)
            ... 47 more
```

Error Log: SSL Exception Part

```
 Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1946)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:316)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:310)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1639)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:223)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1037)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:965)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1064)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:396)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:355)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:373)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:394)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performHttpRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:132)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performHttpRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:109)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.executeGetOrHead(HttpClientHelper.java:98)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:89)
        ... 67 more
    Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:397)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:302)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:262)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1621)
        ... 89 more
    Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:392)
        ... 95 more
```

Comment: What version of Java were you running ? I mean which exact version, like 1.8.0_241-b07

Answer (score 1):

If you are behind a proxy you should have the following in your gradle.properties file.

```
 systemProp.http.proxyHost=proxy_url
 systemProp.http.proxyPort=proxy_port
 systemProp.http.proxyUser=USER
 systemProp.http.proxyPassword=PWD
 systemProp.https.proxyHost=proxy_url 
 systemProp.https.proxyPort=proxy_port
 systemProp.https.proxyUser=USER
 systemProp.https.proxyPassword=PWD
```

If you always have the same problem, you should add the jcenter certicate to your JVM's cacerts.

[image: Jcenter certificate]

If your jcenter certificate is inside any other certificate you should add all certificates to the JVM's cacerts using this command

```
sudo keytool -import -alias jcenter -keystore  PathToYourCacertFile(in my case :/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts) -file path to your cer file (in my case /Users/****/Desktop/jcenter.cer
```

Comment: No i am not behind any proxy and i had downloaded the jcenter certificate and added it directly inside Android Studio but that also did not work. 
Is it always compulsory that the issuer name in the certificate should always be CA because in my case whether i am on a proxy or not , be it office network or home network ..... the issuer name is always coming as proxy.mycompanyname.com

Comment: Check your Network setting if the issuer name is always the same you may have your company's network proxy setted.
Importing the jcenter certificate into Android Studio doesn't work for me also.
You Should import it to your JVM instalation folder /Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts and it will work fine.

Comment: I tried importing the certificate through keytool but still facing the same issue. ERROR: Cause: unable to find valid certification path to requested target.

Also I checked that when Android Studio itself adds a certificate the issuer name is my company name however if i download the certificate from the site itself then the issuer name is different.